# (virt-manager:4796): Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon / Unable to connect to libvirt

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, d-bus, libvirt

I would like to boot and run Windows 8 with kvm or xen while I'm running Debian Wheezy. Actually I have installed Windows 8 on the external USB disk and Debian Wheezy on the hard disk sata. I'm tryng to use the virtual machine manager. Problem is that I'm not able to make it work properly. Infact,I have tried to launch it in two different way,like this :

```
root@localhost:/home/marietto# virt-manager --no-fork

p11-kit: invalid config filename, will be ignored in the future: /etc/pkcs11/modules/gnome-keyring-module
/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-manager.py:306: DeprecationWarning: Importing dbus.glib to use the GLib main loop with dbus-python is deprecated.
Instead, use this sequence:

from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)

import dbus.glib

(virt-manager:4796): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

and like this :

```
marietto@localhost:~$ virt-manager --no-fork

Unable to connect to libvirt.

Verify that the 'libvirtd' daemon is running.

Libvirt URI is: qemu:///system

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 1185, in _open_thread
self.vmm = self._try_open()
File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 1167, in _try_open
flags)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 102, in openAuth
if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virConnectOpenAuth() failed')
libvirtError: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': File o directory non esistente
```

but it didn't work in both cases. can you give me some suggest to fix the problem ? thanks.